# Get text value of span in repeater by using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text

i can't get value of span (or label) 
here is my html code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_district" runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate>
            <tbody id='bodies'>

                <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="district_id"><%# Eval("DISTRICT_ID") %></span>
                </td>
                <td><%# Eval("DISTRICT_NAME") %></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lb_city_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CITY_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="float:left; margin-left:5px;">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_status" runat="server" onclick="javascript: return false;" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_status" Value='<%# Eval("ENABLE") %>' runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="float:left; margin-left:4px;" >
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ib_edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Hinh/icons/Edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:left; margin-left:4px;">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ib_delete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Hinh/icons/Trash.png" 
                                        ToolTip="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DISTRICT_ID") %>'
                                        OnClientClick="getvalue(); return false;"/>

                    </div>
                </td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

i want to get value of district_id in span tag (or label is ok) by using javascript when clicking on imagebutton

```
function getvalue() {
    var thisspan = $('.district_id').eq(0);
    alert(thisspan);
}
```

but it just get the value in first column be cause of ea(0)
i'm just want to get value by using javascript or jquery not code behind
thanks.....

Comment: add a class to the ImageButton & pick up the value of the first instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML, no two elements can have the same ID. Your repeater is creating multiple elements with the same ID. In the JavaScript, you are selecting a class with jQuery instead of an ID. Change it to a class in your html.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, let me know and we can try to see what else might be the problem.

Comment: thank you! i've changed like this: 
`<span id="district_id" class="district_id"><%# Eval("DISTRICT_ID") %></span>`

and javascript
`var thisspan = $('.district_id').text();`

but it append all value from span tag column, i want to get only 1 value of the column when mouse clicked in image

Comment: haha, finally i did it. i added id attribute to <tr> tag and using jquery to get value of it. many thanks to @rescuecreative. I still have one problem. if you have time please help me once more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144418/how-to-export-html5-table-to-excel-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are searching after a class but you have an id

var thisspan = $('#district_id').eq(0);

Answer (score 0):

. is the selector for classes and # is selector for ids. Your html has the id not the class, so your code should be like:

```
var thisspan = $('#district_id').eq(0);
```

Also, id's are unique in html so you do not need the .eq(0):

```
var thisspan = $('#district_id');
```

Finally, to get the text value inside of the span tah you need to do:

```
var thisspan = $('#district_id').html();
```

or

```
var thisspan = $('#district_id').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a css class to your image button like this. No two elements in the DOM should have the same ID.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ib_delete" CssClass="imgClass" ..../>
```

The below will give you the value of the 1st instance of the image button.

```
console.log($('.imgClass').val());
```